# Header row checkbox of radgridview is not getting selected after pagination

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik's RadgridView and RadDataPager for pagination. Behavior is attached for getting all selected records of the grid. But selected records are not maintained while paging (Selected records are cleared when moving to next page).

To solve this, have handled radgridview.Items.PageIndexChanging event to check if the paging is done. Subscribing to this event impacts gridview's header row selection. Checking the header row checkbox (select all option) selects all grid rows but not the header row. on second time checkbox selection selects the header row.

How can I fix this issue?

```
   <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  GroupRenderMode="Flat"
                                  ColumnWidth="*"
                                  Margin="5"
                                  x:Name="radGridViewSupportingDocument"
                                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding PagedSource, ElementName=radDataPagerSupportingDocument}"
                                  common:CustomFilterBehavior.TextBox="{Binding ElementName=radAutoCompleteBoxSearch}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource radGridViewStyle}"
                                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                                  IsReadOnly="True"
                                  >



 <telerik:RadDataPager PageSize="30"
                                   x:Name="radDataPagerSupportingDocument"
                                   Margin="5"
                                   Source="{Binding Documents}"
                                   IsTotalItemCountFixed="True"
                                   DisplayMode="FirstLastPreviousNextNumeric, Text"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Grid.Row="2"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   />




 public class MultiSelectBehavior : Behavior<RadGridView>
    {
        bool _collectionChangedSuspended = false;

        private bool _isPageIndexChanged;
        private ICollection removedItems = null;
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {

            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanging += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanging;
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
            AssociatedObject.Items.PageChanging += Items_PageChanging;
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as RadGridView).Focus();
        }

        void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isPageIndexChanged)
            {
                foreach (var item in removedItems)
                {
                    if (!AssociatedObject.Items.Contains(item))
                    {
                        AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                removedItems = null;
                _isPageIndexChanged = false;
            }
        }

        void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanging(object sender, SelectionChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isPageIndexChanged)
            {
                removedItems = e.RemovedItems;
            }
        }

        void Items_PageChanging(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Data.PageChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            _isPageIndexChanged = true;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged -= GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanging -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanging;
            AssociatedObject.Items.PageChanging -= Items_PageChanging;
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }


         /// <summary>
        /// Getter/Setter for DependencyProperty, bound to the DataContext's SelectedItems ObservableCollection
        /// </summary>
        public INotifyCollectionChanged SelectedItems
        {
            get { return (INotifyCollectionChanged)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dependency Property "SelectedItems" is target of binding to DataContext's SelectedItems
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(MultiSelectBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// PropertyChanged handler for DependencyProperty "SelectedItems"
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            INotifyCollectionChanged collection = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (collection != null)
            {
                // Hook to the Network's SelectedItems
                collection.CollectionChanged += (target as MultiSelectBehavior).ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Will be called, when the Network's SelectedItems collection changes
        /// </summary>
        void ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_collectionChangedSuspended) return;    // Don't react recursively to CollectionChanged events

            _collectionChangedSuspended = true;

            // Select and unselect items in the grid
            if (e.NewItems != null)
                foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);

            if (e.OldItems != null)
                foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);

            _collectionChangedSuspended = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Will be called when the GridView's SelectedItems collection changes
        /// </summary>
        void GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_collectionChangedSuspended) return;    // Don't react recursively to CollectionChanged events

            _collectionChangedSuspended = true;

            // Select and unselect items in the DataContext
            if (e.NewItems != null)
                foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                    (SelectedItems as IList).Add(item);

            if (e.OldItems != null)
                foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                    (SelectedItems as IList).Remove(item);

            _collectionChangedSuspended = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code?

Comment: Please check the code. I am using telerik's SelectColumn for providing checkbox selection.